# Selenium WebDriver Locators

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Код теста авторизации Gmail почты**

Ошибка - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view
Помогите пожалуйста, как решить этот вопрос.

Бонус - вопрос -  дальше шла в секцию имэйлов нажать на кнопку "+", driver1.findElement(By.className("z0")).click(), почему его не обнаруживает??

driver1.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");
driver1.findElement(By.className("z0")).click();

```
package Selenuim_test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


class selenium_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E://gechodriver/geckodriver.exe");



        WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver1.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false");
        driver1.findElement(By.name("identifier")).click();
        driver1.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("nastya.chelyapina0505@gmail.com");

        driver1.findElement(new By.ById("identifierNext")).click();

      driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver1.findElement(By.name("password")).click();
        driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        driver1.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("11111");


        driver1.findElement(new By.ById("passwordNext")).click();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь будет вся загвоздка в динамической загрузке страниц на google.com. Страница открывается быстро, однако не все элементы сразу же подгружаются, это происходит постепенно. Оттого у вашего метода findElement() и не получается сразу же найти необходимый элемент страницы. 
В данном случае возможно будет достаточно неявного ожидания, которым вы пользуетесь:
`driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`,
но разместить его нужно ещё перед открытием страницы, разумеется после создания драйвера.
Так же советую прочитать про явные ожидания.